# How to stop inserting blank row in an Excel File in PHP?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am quite new to **PHPExcel**. I am trying to write a code which reads an Excel file (test.xlsx) and copy specific data into another Excel (dashboard.xlsx)

Here is my code:

```
<?php
   for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex;$col++) {
      $objSheet
         ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row,$worksheet
         >getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)
         ->getValue());
      }
   }
?>
```

The problem that is occurring is that blank rows are being inserted into the file dashboard.xlsx.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Where are the blank rows occurring?  Also, what are theses variables and what values do they hold?  Check out the [tour] (and get a badge!) and also take a look at "[MCVE]" and [ask].

Comment: This might be helpful https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/561